# Which Layout for this JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe

I need your help/advices to find a correct Layout and to organize a JFrame.
Well I have a rather "complicated" JFrame and I don't know which is the best Layout for it.
Am I obliged to use a GridBagLayout ?

If it is the case, can you give some tips in the organisation of the class ?
Each time I use a GridBagLayout the result is kinda random.

[image: JFrame]

Right click to show and zoom picture ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question the other day when I was working on a similar layout. I found this link to be very helpful with gridbag layout configurations.

[GridBagLayout Help](http://blue-walrus.com/?p=582)


You aren't obliged to use a gridbag layout, there are many other layouts that could achieve the desired look and feel. The tutorial in the above link has a similar look and feel to the layout in your picture.

Comment: no, absolute positioning is never a vialable option. Instead, always use a suitable LayoutManager.

Comment: kleopatra is right, "absolute-anything" often leads to catastrophic issues and non-maintenable GUIs.

Answer (score 1):

Try [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).

- Main panel (horizontal) -> Left panel, Table panel
- Left panel (vertical) -> Top panel, Button panel, vertical glue (soaks up empty
  space)
- Top Panel (vertical) -> Info panel 1, etc.
- Info Panel (horizontal) -> Label, Textfield
- Button Panel (horizontal) -> Button 1, Button 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you read french : [See over there](http://bbclone.developpez.com/fr/java/tutoriels/uiswing/gridbaglayout/)

The ref from Oracle : [Follow there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

With only these two links, I get started with this "messy" Layout, which is in fact similar to an HTML table.

Comment: The problem with the Gridbag is that you must think of each "supercell" and how the lines/columns will be merged for that.